# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, permissions, discord.js

When I first wrote these functions, I didn't realize that `.overwritePermissions()` erases set permissions. Coming back to my code after noticing the error, I attempted to update `joinPrivateChannel()` to use `.updateOverwrite()` so as not to erase my channel permissions for the user which creates the channel.

For reference, the first function `createPrivateChannel()` works flawlessly every time, while the second gives me the error `TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.`. I tried hardcoding a user ID, member variable, role ID, and role variable (each in several different ways) but none of these worked. I'm happy to provide/clarify any requested information, thank you for your time.

```
async function createPrivateChannel(serverId, channelName, message) {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(serverId);
  const everyoneRole = guild.roles.everyone;
  const staffRole = guild.roles.Owner;
  const channel = await guild.channels.create(channelName, 'lobby')
  await channel.setParent(lobby_category);
  await channel.overwritePermissions([
    {type: 'member', id: message.author.id, allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
    {type: 'role', id: everyoneRole.id, deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
  ]);
  channel.send('+start');
  return;
}

async function joinPrivateChannel(serverId, channel, message){
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(serverId);
    await channel.updateOverwrite([
        {type: 'member', id: message.author.id, allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the djs doc's `updateOverwrite` doesn't have any syntax with an array. Probably you just misunderstood the parameters.

> `updateOverwrite` have the following parameters: (userOrRole,options,reason).

In your case

```js
await channel.updateOverwrite(message.author.id,
        {VIEW_CHANNEL: true},
    );
```